# Application icon appeared as cogwheel icon on ubuntu 22.04

Tags: icons, 22.04, dock

As you can see spring tool suite icon appeared as a cogwheel icon. Any suggestion on how the actual icon can be displayed??

https://i.stack.imgur.com/3FImo.png

Answer (score 0):

This indicates that the icon defined in the `.desktop` launcher file of that application points to a non existing icon. If the installer program you used does not correctly install the icon, you can still correct this yourself

- Find the `.desktop` file of your application. One way to do this is to use `find` as:

  ```
  find / -name '*.desktop' ! -path '/run/user*' -exec grep -H "Name=Title Displayed In Application Overview" {} \; 2>/dev/null
  ```

  It probably goes without saying that `Title Displayed In Application Overview` should be replaced by the text of the actual label you see under the icon in the application overview.
- Open that `.desktop` launcher with an editor, and take note of the name specified for the icon.
- Put an icon file with the same base name in your `~/.local/share/icons` directory. The extension can be `.png`, `.xpm` or `.svg`. That icon will then be picked up as the icon for that application.

If a full pathname rather than just a name is provided in the `.desktop` launcher, then make sure the icon you create is located in that specific place. However, usually just a basename is provided, allowing the system to search in the standard locations.